# Artifactory: Can the Database Collation be different than the SQL Server Instance?

Tags: sql-server, artifactory, collation

According to the Artifactory documentation "Configuring the Database" (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Microsoft+SQL+Server), for a Microsoft SQL Server database, "set Collation to Latin1_General_CS_AI".

If the collation for the SQL Server (and specifically for tempdb) is "accent sensitive" and the database collation is "accent insensitive", does Artifactory accommodate this configuration?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a problem with different collations. In fact, a *column* can have a different collation. The rest is up to Artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

> If the collation for the SQL Server (and specifically for tempdb) is "accent sensitive" and the database collation is "accent insensitive", does Artifactory accommodate this configuration?

The Artifactory documentation does not say anything about accent insensitivity, though it does specify an accent insensitive Collation (as you stated). Hence, I would give them the benefit of the doubt and assume that they have tested it. They do clearly state on that page:

> **Selecting a Case-sensitive Collation**
>   While Microsoft SQL Database Server is not case-sensitive by default, it is important to select a case-sensitive collation because Artifactory is case-sensitive.

Also, a difference in accent sensitivity is not the focus when wondering if there will be issues with temp tables (assuming that they have queries that JOIN on string fields *and* did not explicitly set a Collation in the `CREATE TABLE #..` statements). Any difference in Collation at all will cause Collation conflict errors with temp tables when JOINing on string columns of differing Collations. It doesn't matter if all of the properties of the two Collations are the same; if there is *any* difference in the Collation name of two columns being JOINed on, there will be an error. So, I think it is safe to assume for the moment that they have accounted for such a scenario, especially since the default Instance Collation is usually accent sensitive.

That said, Instance-level Collation controls (besides the system DBs like `tempdb`): variable names, cursor names, `GOTO` label names, and datatype alias names. If there was going to be a problem with a difference in accent sensitivity, it would be in those areas.